# Should a ceiling fan on a long rod move when using the pull chain?

Tags: installation, ceiling-fan

I installed a 52" ceiling fan in our family room on a 2 foot long downrod. It has a very slight wobble, but nothing of concern since I assumed there would be some wobble due to the length of the rod. However, whenever the pull chain is used on the fan, it tips to the side of the pulling and the rod moves in that direction. The ceilings are sloped and the slot for the downroad "ball" is facing the upward direction of the slope, not the downward direction. This is because the ball will tend to hang down in the direction of the slope.

Is it normal for the fan to "tip" to the direction of the pull chain when it is pulled?

The clevis pin is completely inserted with the cotter pin securely fastened to the clevis pin. Also, both set screws are completely tight. It just seems there is a little play between the motor housing collar where the fan is located and where the downrod is inserted. I looked at the old fan I pulled down that also had a long downrod and it had some play too.

Is this because I am using a longer downrod instead of a shorter downrod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fans are mounted in a ball and socket type joint, both to allow them to self level and to allow a slight movement to reduce vibration being transmitted back up through the mounting hardware to the ceiling. Slight shifting when you tug on one side of a pivoted fan is likely not a concern.

Also, 2 foot downrods (of the proper type) are not at all unusual in standard fan setups.

Answer (score 1):

If the pull chain is off center from the fan assembly then a tug on the string/chain can indeed cause the unit to pull to one side. If you were to pull on the string at any other direction than straight down then I would fully expect that to also cause the fan assembly to pull to one side or another.

The wobbling you see when the fan runs is most likely due to a slight imbalance in the fan motor and rotor assembly. There are some tricks you can do to try to get a better balance. The easiest one is to try swapping adjacent pairs of the fan blades. Also the metal bracket that holds the fan blade assembly to the motor hub may be movable to a slight amount when the hub screws are loosened. Some repositioning of the blades and re-tightening the screws may make some difference in the balance.

Comment: Thanks.. I used the balancing kit that came with the fan and that made the wobbling worse when I used it on the blades. It is very slight and only noticeable when it is on the highest settings. Yes, the pull chain is off center and the fan pulls to that side. I imagine it is like a pendulum. Trying to make sure I did it right since I don't want the fan falling down on my kids. I will try adjusting the mounting bracket if possible.